# Loading and writing to array tables

Tags: c#

Working on my last assignment of the year trying to get into C# and kinda stuck on how to pull the array in and parse it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the actual assignment:

> Write a program to calculate averages. Create a method named ReadData that will load a two-dimensional array, named stuGradesArray, with the following data from a file.
>
> ```
> 1324    75.8    89.3    92.3
> 4356    86.3    83.4    98.3
> 4790    90.1    77.3    76.9
> 8393    73.9    76.3    89.3
> 5563    97.3    78.4    78.9
> 8329    87.3    65.3    77.2
> 2717    67.9    89.3    79.3
> ```
>
> The first number represents the last four digits of a student number. The last three numbers represent test grades. ReadData will have one argument, the stuGradesArray.
>
> Create a method named DisplayAverages that will display the student number and the average of the three test grades. DisplayAverages will have one argument, the stuGradesArray. Your output should closely resemble the following.
>
> ```
> Student #   Test1   Test2   Test3   Average
> 1324        75.8    89.3    92.3    85.8
> 4356        86.3    83.4    98.3    89.3
> 4790        90.1    77.3    76.9    81.4
> 8393        73.9    76.3    89.3    79.8
> 5563        97.3    78.4    78.9    84.9
> 8329        87.3    65.3    77.2    76.6
> 2717        67.9    89.3    79.3    78.8
> ```
>
> Input from the file named Program12Dat.txt, found in Blackboard. Output to a file. Round averages to one decimal place. Passing arguments is important for this program. No global variables are allowed, except for the streamReader and the streamWriter. The stuGradesArray must be declared in Main and passed as an argument to the methods ReadData and DisplayAverages.

And here is what I have  so far.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program11
{

static StreamReader fileIn;
static StreamWriter fileOut;

static void Main()
{
    uint[,] StudentArray = new uint[7, 4];

    ReadData();
    DisplayAverages();
    CloseFiles();
}

private static void DisplayAverages()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

static void ReadData()
{
    uint[,] StudentArray = new uint[7, 4];
    string OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = @"C:\Files\output1.txt";
    string INPUT_FILE_NAME = @"C:\Files\output1.txt";
    if (File.Exists(INPUT_FILE_NAME))
    {
        fileIn = File.OpenText(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        Console.WriteLine("{ 0} was opened", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} does not exist\n", INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    }
    fileOut = File.CreateText(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
    if (File.Exists(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME))
        Console.WriteLine("{0} was created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} could not be created\n", OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);
    }
}
static void DisplayAverages()
    {
    fileOut.WriteLine("                                         Grades Report                                                  ");
    fileOut.WriteLine();
    fileOut.WriteLine("   Student#      Test1    Test2   Test3  Average    FICA    Fed Tax  State Tax  Net Pay ");
    fileOut.WriteLine("--------------- --------------- ---- ----- ----- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------");
}

    static void CloseFiles()
    {
     fileIn.Close(); fileOut.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can anyone help a guy out, Its due in 3 hours and I just want to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution to your assignments. The output file formatting is not as expected but you can play with that.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public const string INPUT_FILE_NAME = @"F:\Program12Dat.txt";
    public const string OUTPUT_FILE_NAME = @"F:\Output.txt";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var stuGradesArray = new double[7, 4];

    ReadData(stuGradesArray);
    DisplayAverages(stuGradesArray);
}

public static void ReadData(double[,] stuGradesArray)
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILE_NAME);

        using (reader)
        {
            int lineNumber = 0;

            // Read first line from the text file
            string line = reader.ReadLine();

            // Read the other lines from the text file
            while (line != null)
            {
                double[] lineNumbers = line.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                           .Select(x => double.Parse(x))
                                           .ToArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < lineNumbers.Length; i++)
                {
                    stuGradesArray[lineNumber, i] = lineNumbers[i];
                }

                lineNumber++;
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

public static void DisplayAverages(double[,] stuGradesArray)
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OUTPUT_FILE_NAME);

    using (writer)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Student #   Test1   Test2   Test3   Average");

        for (int i = 0; i < stuGradesArray.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            var line = string.Empty;
            var average = 0d;
            for (int j = 0; j < stuGradesArray.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                line += stuGradesArray[i, j];
                line += "\t";

                if (j != 0)
                {
                    average += stuGradesArray[i, j];
                }
            }

            line += Math.Round(average / 3, 1);
            writer.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

}